# Understanding the importance of 'pitch': For ball screws and timing belts

Tags: linear-motion

I searched here and even asked at McMaster-Carr, but even they couldn't provide an answer for me--

So, say you have either a ball-screw, or a timing belt-- Of course, in either case, having the right screw or belt for the geared purpose is 'quite important'.

However, I wondered if, in the end, the 'pitch' actually, at all, affected 'precision' in any reasonable way.

Abstractly, the easiest way for me to think of this is in the case of a 'ball screw'.

Lets say you have a 'really high pitch'-- Obviously for each turn of the screw, you are going to 'get where you are going' *much* faster than a very tight pitch.

That would require ever more turns of the screw--

Yet, between the two, it seems to me, between the high pitch, and low pitch screw, you should always be able to reach the 'same degree of position accuracy'-- *at least* if you are able to turn the screw slow enough (smaller, rather than bigger steps).

Am I wrong in this ?

With regard to 'timing belts', it is harder for me to think about. Would the principle be the same ?

Comment: "*at least if you are able to turn the screw slow enough (smaller, rather than bigger steps).*" That's a big if and not something to be hand waved. In addition it affects the torque required. With regards to timing belts, higher pitch lets you use smaller pulleys. That *could* translate to obtaining higher positional accuracy more easily if you're gearing things up and down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ball screw converts the rotational position of the shaft to a linear position of the carriage. In a typical application of ball screws, like a servo linear axis or the cross slide of a lathe, the rotation is controlled, not the actual linear motion.

Example: on a lathe, you turn the dial which has gradation that represent linear displacement, but as you turn the wheel to a certain rotational position, you control the rotation - not the linear displacement directly. A servo controlling a linear motion often has a rotary encoder as its position feedback mechanism. Same story applies.

This control of rotational angle will have a limited resolution, repeatability and absolute accuracy. Same as the ball screw converts a rotational position to linear position, with conversion proportional to the pitch of the screw, it converts a rotational angle error to a linear position error that is proportional to the pitch.

Example:

- 1/100 of revolution error at 5 mm pitch: linear position error = 0.01*5=0.05 mm
- 1/100 of revolution error at 25 mm pitch: linear position error = 0.01*25=0.25 mm

Comment: On the timing belt, here the radius of the pulley determines the conversion factor of rotational position and error on this position. Analogously to the ball screw pitch, a larger pulley will convert a rotational error to a larger linear position error than a smaller pulley.